# Generate RSA-PSS Signature

Tags: rsa, abap

How can we use the RSA-PSS Algo to create a Signature in ABAP?

Currently we use the following function: `SSFW_KRN_SIGN` with the `str_format = 'PKCS1-V1.5'`.
In the future we will need 'SHA256withRSA/PSS' Algo.

Please provide a code example. Thank you!

Comment: What screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 different technical information given with "SHA256withRSA/PSS". SHA256 is hashing algorithm for your data. RSA is a public/private key couple and PSS is a padding algorithm. SSFW_KRN_SIGN using sapcryptolib. You need to update this library (basis can do this) to get new padding and hashing algorithms. Check the note [1848999](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1848999) for which version supports your minimum requirements. I see that you need to use at least v8.4.15.

You can check your current version with SSF01/SSF02.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be back in office on Monday and check with my team! After that I'll accept this answer as correct :)