# How to create a RSA-PSS Signature in ABAP?

Tags: rsa, abap

I want to create an RSA-PSS Signature with ABAP. For Signatures can the function module `CALL FUNCTION 'SSFW_KRN_SIGN'` be used. It works fine with PKCS1-V1.5, but I need to use RSA-PSS-Padding.

I also found [Generate RSA-PSS Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74748467/generate-rsa-pss-signature), but this solution does not solve my issue.

I would really appreciate a small code example, on how I can sign a string `lv_str` with an SSFA-Store from my SAP system?

I tried different `str_format` Parameters but none were right.
My Current SSF version is SSFLIB Version 1.850.40 ; CommonCryptoLib (SAPCRYPTOLIB) Version 8.5.39 (+MT) #Copyright (c) SAP, 2011-2021#compiled for linux-gcc-4.3-x86-64#

With @robert-stefanov 's solution my working code on CommonCryptoLib (SAPCRYPTOLIB) Version 8.5.44 is the following:

```
    CALL FUNCTION 'SSF_GET_PARAMETER'
    EXPORTING
      mandt                   = sy-mandt
      application             = iv_ssfa
    IMPORTING
      str_profileid           = ls_ssfinfo-id
      str_profile             = ls_ssfinfo-profile
    EXCEPTIONS
      ssf_parameter_not_found = 1
      OTHERS                  = 2.

  IF sy-subrc NE 0.
    MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
               WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
  ENDIF.

  APPEND ls_ssfinfo TO lt_ssfinfo.

  CALL FUNCTION 'SSFW_KRN_SIGN'
    EXPORTING
      str_format                   = 'PKCS1-PSS'
      str_hashalg                  = 'SHA256'
      ostr_input_data              = lv_xstr
    IMPORTING
      ostr_signed_data             = lv_signed_xstr
      crc                          = lv_rc
    TABLES
      signer                       = lt_ssfinfo
    EXCEPTIONS
      ssf_krn_error                = 1
      ssf_krn_noop                 = 2
      ssf_krn_nomemory             = 3
      ssf_krn_opinv                = 4
      ssf_krn_nossflib             = 5
      ssf_krn_signer_list_error    = 6
      ssf_krn_input_data_error     = 7
      ssf_krn_invalid_par          = 8
      ssf_krn_invalid_parlen       = 9
      ssf_fb_input_parameter_error = 10
      OTHERS                       = 11.

  IF sy-subrc NE 0.
    MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
               WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
  ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct `str_format` is `'PKCS1-PSS'`.
But your SAPCRYPTOLIB Version 8.5.39 is not enough.
You have to update it. It was tested successfully with 8.5.42 and Kernel 7.53 pl800.

Comment: This is works. How did you get this Information? So next time I dont have to ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: Function group SSFW has a test class defined in include LSSFWT99. There is `'PKCS1-OAEP'` encrypion example to be found. Following the naming convention I tried PKCS1-PSS for signing and it worked. So it was a lucky guess.